# xsltforms in exist-db no longer rendering in browsers

Tags: google-chrome, xslt, exist-db, xsltforms

yesterday morning I was happily working on my xsltforms in a hosted exist-db environment and at lunchtime, my chrome version updated. Since then, the forms load only white screens. Asking my colleagues, it turns out that these forms stopped being viewable in Edge and Firefox as well, sometime in the last few weeks. My laptop (not updated) still views the forms fine (or did until this morning when it's version of chrome also updated).

There is no error in the console (post edited for this) and the sources correctly list both the xml and the xsl fie. But the screen stays completely blank...

Nothing has changed in the config (and like I say the forms were working in the older version of chrome).

Any ideas on how to get them back?

Cheers
Ralph

Comment: Well, Edge and Chrome use the same rendering engine for some while now so a change there in the Chromium engine can of course affect both Chrome and Edge users. But Firefox has its own rendering engine so it sounds odd that the loss of rendering should be related to the browsers. Are there at least any warnings in the console, even if there are no errors? What does the inspector show, are there any elements or other nodes generated, perhaps just not HTML ones you see "rendered"?

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, literally the only thing in the elements tab for chrome/edge is: 'xml-stylesheet'. Nothing else. Console is empty, and sources lists the correct xml, which worked pre-update. Network shows the xml loading and then the xsl loading (both link correctly). No error messages at all. Firefox does show an error: Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed, but with no further details...

Comment: Using XSLTForms without exist-db, I cannot see any issue with updated browsers, even with Google Chrome Canary. Please give a try at http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms/hello.xml

Comment: Thanks @AlainCouthures, I'm fairly confident that it is not an XSLT thing, but it is definitely tied to the Chrome updates (worked yesterday morning on two pcs, this morning on one, now none). I'm suspecting a java issue, and I'm sure it's going to be either in my broswer or the xsl instructions on exist-db (for info 1.5.5 (661)) but I'm struggling to see what it could be...

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by upgrading the XSLTforms main files from v.661 to v.662 (https://github.com/AlainCouthures/declarative4all/tree/master/public/direct). Not at all sure why this made such a dramatic difference, or why the fault suddenly kicked in on browser upgrade, but at least it's fixed.